# MS-SQL server 2008r2 selecting the time from smalltimedate irrespective of date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a smalltimedate column and want to do the equivalent to a wild card search on it and find all rows that have times of 00:00:00 irrespective of the date.

eg

```
id  | col

1  |  2014-01-01 00:01:00
2  |  2014-01-02 00:01:00
3  |  2014-01-03 00:00:00
4  |  2014-01-04 00:00:00
```

would return

```
id  |  col

3  |  2014-01-03 00:00:00
4  |  2014-01-04 00:00:00
```

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),col,108) = '00:00:00'
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    col SMALLDATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @t (id, col)
VALUES
    (1, '2014-01-01 00:01:00'),
    (2, '2014-01-02 00:01:00'),
    (3, '2014-01-03 00:00:00'),
    (4, '2014-01-04 00:00:00')

SELECT *
FROM @t
WHERE CAST(col AS FLOAT) - ROUND(CAST(col AS FLOAT), 0) = 0
```

Output -

```
id          col
----------- -----------------------
3           2014-01-03 00:00:00
4           2014-01-04 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
select 
  *
from
  T
where
  cast(col as time) = '00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 1):

Ugly, but...

```
SELECT ...
WHERE DATEPART(hour, col) = 0 AND DATEPART(minute, col) = 0 AND DATEPART(second,col) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE CONVERT(CHAR(10),col,108) = '00:00:00'